# Hibernate Update method throws cast exception

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I' m trying to see table outputs of some operation of Hibernate and i faced an issue. Scenario is that i have only 1 Class named as pojo. I create a `new Pojo()` then calling `session.merge()` method. then calling the `session.update()` method in another transaction. However, it throws below exception

Pojo.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POJO_TABLE")
@SelectBeforeUpdate
public class Pojo {
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "POJO_TABLE_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 500)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String addressStr;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_BYTE", columnDefinition = "BLOB")
    private byte[] addressByte;

    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "DATE")
    private Date date;

    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIME)
    @Column(name = "TIME")
    private Date time;

    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "DATETIME")
    private Date datetime;

    //setter/getter methods
}
```

main method is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
        pojo.setName("Name");
        pojo.setLastName("Lastname");
        pojo.setDate(new Date());
        pojo.setDatetime(new Date());
        pojo.setTime(new Date());
        pojo.setAddressStr("Istanbul");
        pojo.setAddressByte("Istanbul".getBytes());


        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.getTransaction().begin();
        Pojo pojo2 = (Pojo) session.merge(pojo);
        pojo.setId(pojo2.getId());
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.getTransaction().begin();
        session.update(pojo);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

if i use `@SelectBeforeUpdate` annotation, following exception is thrown. This annotation makes select before update operation to find dirty values. I debugged source code of hibernate and saw that existing entity properties size is 6, but entity loaded from db property size is 7. Hibernate base logic does not select id as a property for existing entity, but id is selected as a property for entity loaded from DB. that is why sizes do not equals. Exception is below. what is the problem? any idea? Thanks in advance.

```
Hibernate: insert into POJO_TABLE (ADDRESS_BYTE, ADDRESS, DATE, DATETIME, LASTNAME, NAME, TIME, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select p1_0.ID, p1_0.ADDRESS_BYTE, p1_0.ADDRESS, p1_0.DATE, p1_0.DATETIME, p1_0.LASTNAME, p1_0.NAME, p1_0.TIME from POJO_TABLE as p1_0 where p1_0.ID = ?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to [B
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.areEqual(PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.isEqual(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.isSame(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.isDirty(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.isModified(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.findModified(TypeHelper.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.findModified(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4728)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.dirtyCheck(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:611)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.isUpdateNecessary(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1335)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2655)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:1823)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:442)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at application.PojoApp.main(PojoApp.java:42)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and it is caused by LATEST version of it. (currently 6.0.0.Alpha6).

when i use following depedency, it throws an exception.

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0.Alpha6</version>
</dependency>
```

It works when i use version `5.4.12.Final`. It is Hibernate' s bug.
Also `between` query(see below) does not work within latest version. it throws stackOverFlowException because of recursion calls.

```
 Query query = em.createQuery("select item from Item item where stockQuantity between :min and :max", Item.class);
 query.setParameter("min", 10);
 query.setParameter("max", 20);
 return query.getResultList();

 //exception is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmMappingModelHelper.resolveSqmPath(SqmMappingModelHelper.java:140)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmMappingModelHelper.resolveMappingModelExpressable(SqmMappingModelHelper.java:109)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.determineValueMapping(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:1064)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.lambda$visitBetweenPredicate$19(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:2312)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.determineValueMapping(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:1103)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.determineValueMapping(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:1059)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.lambda$visitBetweenPredicate$19(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:2313)
```